# Problems with query to get the desired result

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

---

### DDL for Table APPLICATION_STATUS_PROPOSALS

```
CREATE TABLE "USTDMS"."APPLICATION_STATUS_PROPOSALS" 
("EMPNO" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
"COLLEGE_ID" NUMBER(2,0), 
"PROPOSAL_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
"DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(1,0), 
"APPROVAL_CHAIRMAN" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0,  
"APPROVED_DATE_CHAIRMAN" DATE, 
"REMARKS_CHAIRMAN" VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),  
"TIMESTAMP_CHAIRMAN" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
```

---

### DDL for Table PROPOSALS

```
 CREATE TABLE "USTDMS"."PROPOSALS" 
("EMPNO" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
"COLLEGE_ID" NUMBER(2,0), 
"PROPOSAL_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
"DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(1,0), 
"PROJECT_TITLE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
"PROPONENTS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"BIRTH_DATE" DATE, 
"HOME_ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"BUSINESS_ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"ACADEMIC_RANK" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"CONTACT_NO" NUMBER(15,0), 
"COOPERATING_AGENCIES" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
"OBJECTIVES" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
"PROJECT_SIGNIFICANCE" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
"PROJECT_STATUS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"TOTAL_PROJ_FEE" NUMBER(10,0), 
"RESEARCH_CENTER" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE), 
"SUBMITTED_DATE" DATE, 
"TIMESTAMP" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
"CATEGORY" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
```

So I have 2 data in the database currently and this is the script I'm using to fetch proposals whose approved status by the Chairman is 1(approved)

```
select p.EMPNO, p.COLLEGE_ID, p.PROPOSAL_ID,p.DEPARTMENT_ID,p.PROJECT_TITLE, 
p.PROPONENTS, p.CATEGORY, p.SUBMITTED_DATE, p.TIMESTAMP,
p.PROJECT_SIGNIFICANCE, p.OBJECTIVES, p.TOTAL_PROJ_FEE from USTDMS.PROPOSALS p, 
USTDMS.APPLICATION_STATUS_PROPOSALS a WHERE p.COLLEGE_ID = a.COLLEGE_ID AND 
p.COLLEGE_ID=26 AND a.APPROVAL_CHAIRMAN = 1;
```

The 1st and 2nd data have the same college id but the 1st data's approval is 1 while the 2nd is 0. The resulting set of the query is still the both data. How can I fix my query to get my desired result?

**EDITED**

```
Insert into USTDMS.APPLICATION_STATUS_PROPOSALS (EMPNO,COLLEGE_ID,PROPOSAL_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID,
APPROVAL_CHAIRMAN,APPROVED_DATE_CHAIRMAN,REMARKS_CHAIRMAN,TIMESTAMP_CHAIRMAN) values
```

1st data

```
('2014072880',26,4818899083,3,1,to_date('03/08/2018','MM/DD/RRRR'),'16:29:44.964');
```

2nd data

```
('2013061644',26,4247805062,1,0,null,null);
```

Initial Result of my script: both data is selected;
Desired Result of my script: only the 1st data will be selected since its approval_Chairman is 1(accepted).

Comment: You need to join the two tables on fields that together uniquely identify a proposal.

Comment: Please add sample records and expected result records in your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @KlasLindbäck edited

Comment: @ArtBajji edited

Comment: @KlasLindbäck so I should another constraint to the query? ->  (where PROPOSAL_ID =  ?)

Comment: Yes! If `PROPOSAL_ID` is the primary key for the `PROPOSAL` table then you need the constraint `a.PROPOSAL_ID = p.PROPOSAL_ID`.

Comment: Alright! Thank you Sir for the answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also include joins on EMPNO, PROPOSAL_ID and DEPARTMENT_ID.

```
select p.EMPNO, p.COLLEGE_ID, p.PROPOSAL_ID,p.DEPARTMENT_ID,p.PROJECT_TITLE, 
       p.PROPONENTS, p.CATEGORY, p.SUBMITTED_DATE, p.TIMESTAMP,
       p.PROJECT_SIGNIFICANCE, p.OBJECTIVES, p.TOTAL_PROJ_FEE 
  from USTDMS.PROPOSALS p
       inner join
       USTDMS.APPLICATION_STATUS_PROPOSALS a 
    on p.COLLEGE_ID = a.COLLEGE_ID 
   and p.EMPNO = a.EMPNO
   and p.PROPOSAL_ID = a.PROPOSAL_ID
   and p.DEPARTMENT_ID = a.DEPARTMENT_ID
 WHERE p.COLLEGE_ID=26 
   AND a.APPROVAL_CHAIRMAN = 1;
```